# How to implement mod function in Solr 3.3

Tags: solr, lucene, modulo

I am using solr 3.3 now, and there is need to using mod function in query,but mod function is not exist until 4.0. so, I want using other functionsto replace mod in 3.3 like

```
q=subject:mp3&fq={!frange l=1 u=1}sub(id,product(floor(div(id,2)),2)).
```

But I found that this function can not working, cause that  sub(id,product(floor(div(id,2)),2)) will
equal to id even id is a odd number. Is there anyone can given a working replacement for mod function in 3.3? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already written some Java, it should be easy to implement, just write a `ModFunction` class (see the [div implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.3.0/org/apache/solr/search/function/DivFloatFunction.java#DivFloatFunction) for example). Then write a `ValueSourceParser` for it, it should look like:

```
public class ModFunctionParser extends ValueSourceParser {
  @Override
  public ValueSource parse(FunctionQParser fp) throws ParseException {
    ValueSource a = fp.parseValueSource();
    ValueSource b = fp.parseValueSource();
    return new ModFunction(a, b);
  }
}
```

And finally, [register this parser in your solrconfig.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#ValueSourceParser).